# Регулярное выражение для телефона

Tags: регулярные-выражения, javascript

Помогите с регулярным выражением в котором допустимы только пробелы, скобки, цифры и тире.
Количество символов не ограничено, и телефон может быть написан в свободной форме, например: 8 (928) 999 99-99 или +7-4242 25-25-25.

Answer (score 2):

```
if( $phone =~ /^[0-9()\-+ ]+$/ )
{
    $phone =~ s/[^0-9]//g; 
    # теперь в телефоне только цифры, и можем проверять их валидность
}
else
{
    # облом
}
```

Comment: /^[0-9()\-+ ]+$/ подходит для телефона в свободной форме.

Comment: Что-то это не js :)

Comment: @lmsha, не подходит - плюсы внутри разрешаешь.

Answer (score 0):

Зачем сочинять велосипед, когда есть готовые плагины для jQuery: [Masked Input Plugin](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/)

Ну или на крайняк сможете посмотреть там реализацию. От себя скажу что плагин очень удобный и гибкий, использовал его в своих проектах.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( value.match(/^([\+]+)*[0-9\x20\x28\x29\-]{5,20}$/) ) // телефон
```

А вообще лучше так:

```
value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '').length // проверять на количество цифр, остающихся после
```

Хотя, тоже не торт.

Телефоны какой страны, вы хотите отпарсить регуляркой?

Comment: /^([\+]+)*[0-9\x20\x28\x29\-]{5,20}$/
подходит для телефона в классическом написании, например 8 (922) 922 99-22

Answer (score -3):

```
/\+?[-() \d]+/
```

PS: 30 символов для ответа надо :(